# Viewing the returned string of openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Tags: php, casting, return-type, php-openssl

Why doesn't `echo openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12)` print out anything but if I concatenate it with another string it does show the output? According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) the return type of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is a string so why is there a problem? I tried type casting it with `(string)` and it didn't work.

Comment: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(...)` function returns a binary number in the form of a string (i.e. ASCII value(s)) of the specified length.

For example, one possible output of:

```
$number_of_bytes = 1;
$bin = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($number_of_bytes, $cstrong);
$hex=bin2hex($bin);
$dec=hexdec($hex);
```

could be:

```
var_dump($bin); // string(1) "ã"
var_dump($hex); // string(2) "e3"
var_dump($dec); // int(227)
var_dump($cstrong); // bool(true)
```

Notes:

1. `$dec` is an integer random value that can be equal to (at most) 2 ^ (8 * $number_of_bytes) - 1.

   - where one byte comprises 8 bits
   - PHP has a *integer overflow **limitation*** of at most 2^31-1 or 2^63-1 bits (the limits of signed integers which use 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on whether you have a 32 or 64 bit platform respectively) , after which it overflows / casts into a float value (potentially limiting precision).

     - so calling with 4 (or 8) bytes, half of the time `$dec` would be a float
2. At higher numbers of bytes, the `$bin` and `$hex` values maintain their precision and accuracy  (because all of the digits/bits are kept in a (variable length) string).
3. `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` returns `false` when it fails.
4. `$cstrong!==true` indicates `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` did  not return a result generated by a cryptographically strong algorithm. (http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes)

---

Example Function (demonstrates handling a `false` return value or when $cstrong is false)

```
class Random
{
    public static function Get($number_of_bytes=4)
    {
        $binary_value = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($number_of_bytes, $cstrong);

        // Unable to produce a cryptographically strong value
        if($binary_value==false || $cstrong!==true) return false; // failure

        // other processing
        $hexadecimal_value = bin2hex($binary_value);
        $decimal_value = hexdec($hexadecimal_value);  

        // Returns a positive integer (or a float 
        // in the case of an integer overflow)
        return $decimal_value; 
    }
}
```

manual: http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Usage

```
echo Random::Get(12); // returns a large float value most of the time
```